# How to distinguish between different wifi networks?

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-networking

If there are two wifi networks in range that both have the same SSID, security type, and password, is there any available ID to distinguish between them? Is there a way to get that ID in android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can distinguish them through `BSSID` - if someone won't assign fixed `MAC` address they will have for sure different (unique) `MAC` addresses.

Also they can be on different channel. I think it's impossible if two networks have same `SSID`, same channel and same `BSSID`.

Comment: so I should only check `BSSID` or `BSSID` and `SSID` and channel or `MAC`? which always work correctly?

Comment: I think that check BSSID is enough but still you can check also channel.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to extract the MAC address from the sending networks Router/AP. This address would be unique.

Answer (score 1):

use [getSubtype()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) .

Check out slide 9 [here](https://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/W_0300_CodingforLife-BatteryLifeThatIs.pdf):

```
ConnectivityManager mConnectivity = null;
TelephonyManager mTelephony = null;
// Skip if no connection, or background data disabled
NetworkInfo info = mConnectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (info == null || !mConnectivity.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
    return false;
}

// Only update if WiFi or 3G is connected and not roaming
int netType = info.getType();
int netSubtype = info.getSubtype();
if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
    return info.isConnected();
} else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
    && netSubtype == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
    && !mTelephony.isNetworkRoaming()) {
        return info.isConnected();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what is returned by `getSubtype()` ?